# Config Yaml to run PHP and Python with AJAX in the same project with App engine

Tags: php, python, ajax, google-app-engine

I have one idea of project

[image]

```
$.ajax({
 url: '../server/python/python_file.py',
 dataType: 'json',
 type: 'POST',
 success:function(data) {
  //Make other AJAX request with PHP files 
 },
 error: function(error){
  console.log(error);
 }
});
```

But how to config app.yaml if runtime is set to php55

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have two different languages in the same app engine instance.

What you can do is creating two conf files : `app.python.yaml` and `app.php.yaml`

Then you will be able to deploy them with :

`gcloud app deploy -f app.<language>.yaml`

But you will have two separate App Engine instances (So you will be charge for two instances).